# Chrome firinng onChange event when month is changed for input type="date"

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome

I am using an input type="date" to allow the user to select dates.

In Firefox/Safari/Edge the onChange event doesn't fire unless a date is selected (you can press the forward/backward month buttons and the onChange does NOT fire).

However, in Chrome, if you select a date, then open the calendar again and navigate the month, Chrome will fire the onChange event with a date value for the new month in event.target.value.

Is there a way to protect against this to get consistent behavior across browsers?  I've tried setting the value for the input field to null/undefined but that hasn't helped.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { InputFieldChange } from "../../../constants";
import { format, addDays } from "date-fns";
import styles from "./date-picker-list.module.css";

export interface OwnProps {
  id: string;
  formData: any;
  helpText: string;
  label: string;
  isRequired: boolean;
  onChange: (value: InputFieldChange) => void;
}

export default function DatePickerList(props: OwnProps) {
  const [dateList, setDateList] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [minDate, setMinDate] = useState<string>("");
  const [maxDate, setMaxDate] = useState<string>("");
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [helpTextId, setHelpTextId] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [validationError, setValidationError] = useState<string>("");
  const [validationClass, setValidationClass] =
    useState<string>("form-control");

  useEffect(() => {
    const today = new Date();
    const minDate = format(addDays(today, -1), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    const maxDate = format(addDays(today, 90), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    setMinDate(minDate);
    setMaxDate(maxDate);
    setDateValue(null);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.helpText == null) {
      setHelpTextId(null);
    } else {
      setHelpTextId(props.id + "_helper");
    }

    var dateListValues = props.formData[props.id];
    if (dateListValues) {
      setDateList(dateListValues.split(","));
    }
  }, [props.helpText, props.id, props.formData]);

  function isValid(valueList: string[]): boolean {
    let validationError = "";

    if (props.isRequired && valueList.length == 0) {
      validationError = "This is a required field";
    }

    if (validationError != "") {
      setValidationClass("form-control is-invalid");
    } else {
      if (props.isRequired) {
        setValidationClass("form-control is-valid");
      } else {
        setValidationClass("form-control");
      }
    }

    setValidationError(validationError);
    return validationError == "";
  }

  const addDateToList = (e: any) => {
    console.log("add date to tlist event CHANGE: ", e)
    const dateToAdd = e.target.value;
    let dateExists = dateList.filter((d) => d == dateToAdd);
    if (dateExists.length == 0) {
      let valueList = dateList.filter((d) => d == d);
      valueList.push(dateToAdd);
      isValid(valueList);
      setDateList(valueList);
      setDateValue(null);
      props.onChange({ field: props.id, value: valueList.toString(), validationMessage: "" });
    }
  };

  const removeDateFromList = (dateToRemove) => {
    let valueList = dateList.filter((d) => d != dateToRemove);
    setDateList(valueList);

    if (isValid(valueList)) {
      props.onChange({ field: props.id, value: valueList.toString(), validationMessage: "" });
    }
    else {
      props.onChange({ field: props.id, value: valueList.toString(), validationMessage: "This is a required field" });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor={props.id} className="form-label">
        {props.label}
        {props.isRequired == true ? <span className="label-required">
          *
        </span> : null}
      </label>
      <input
        type="date"
        className={validationClass}
        id={props.id}
        name={props.id}
        onChange={(e) => addDateToList(e)}
        required={props.isRequired}
        value={dateValue}
        min={minDate}
        max={maxDate}
        aria-describedby={props.helpText == null ? null : helpTextId}
      />
      <div className={styles.dateListContainer}>
        {dateList?.map((date, index) => (
          <div className={styles.dateListPill} key={index}>
            <div className={styles.dateListItem}>{date}</div>
            <div
              className={styles.xCircleFill}
              aria-label={"Remove " + date}
              onClick={() => removeDateFromList(date)}
            >
              X
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      {validationError == "" ? null : (
        <div className="invalid-feedback">{validationError}</div>
      )}
      {props.helpText == null ? null : (
        <div id={helpTextId} className="form-text">
          {props.helpText}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```